# Create Outlook 365 events via API for multiple users

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth, office365api

Our CRM creates activities that can have one or more participants. What we want to do is:

- First allow each user to authenticate our Office APP to read/write their Outlook Calendar.
- When an activity is created in our system we should make an event for each participant/user who has authenticated our APP.

In order to do so, I believe, we will store the OAuth access token in database so we can use it later to read/write outlook events on the user's behalf.

Microsoft's documentation is kind of vague on this feature. So the question is:

- Can an application create calendar events on Outlook365 via REST API for multiple office users if they each have authorized the app and we have the access tokens stored in database.

Almost all the examples and sample code I have seen involves only the currently logged in user.

Answer (score 1):

I asked another question and got an answer (only after a few minutes) som possibly can help you too. 
Take a look at the Microsoft Graph API, "Get Access without a user": https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service

Here is the link to my question:
[O365 Outlook REST API, masquerading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209564/o365-outlook-rest-api-masquerading/48209777?noredirect=1#comment83401451_48209777)